# How to clear a selection from a Bokeh plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I use selection in a figure to drive my Bokeh server application.  However after the user selects something I don't actually want that selection to have any visual effect on the figure. How can I remove the selection effects?

I can imagine two ways of solving this, but am having trouble getting either to work:

1. Remove the selection in the callback

   ```
   def cb(attr, old, new):
       source.selected.indices.clear()
       ...

   source.on_change('selected', cb)
   ```
2. Keep the selected indices, but remove any styling difference between them. I found this:

   http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs

   but wasn't sure how to effectively apply this to my problem.

Comment: I have written an [**GH issue**](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7944) some days ago, about updating selected indexes programmatically. Take a look at it and check if you want to add anything else.

Comment: Hrm, that is useful. Thanks for the pointer @ChesuCR .  In the meantime do you have any suggestions for opiton 2, removing style differences between selected and non-selected glyphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection/non-selection glyphs can be either disabled or use the main glyph, e.g.:

```
r = plot.scatter(...)
r.selection_glyph = None
r.nonselection_glyph = None
```

or

```
r = plot.scatter(...)
r.selection_glyph = r.glyph
r.nonselection_glyph = r.glyph
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to hide the selection indices you can do what Mateusz says.

Normally you would have only a glyph with selected and non-selected elements like this:

```
c = self.plot.scatter(
    x='x',
    y='x',
    size=4,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='blue',
    source=source,
    view=view,

    nonselection_line_color=None,
    nonselection_fill_color='blue',
    nonselection_fill_alpha=1.0,
)
c.selection_glyph = Circle(
    line_color=None,
    line_alpha=1.0,
    fill_color='red',
)
```

But, if you want to change the selection, and keep the selections color on the custom selection (previous selection), as a workaround you can manage another list `custom_selection` with the samples that are actually selected. So you would need to create two glyphs, one for the selected and another one with the non-selected samples. Something like this:

```
c = self.plot.scatter(
    x='x',
    y='x',
    size=4,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='blue',
    source=source,
    view=view_non_selected,          # here the view should have the non-selected samples

    nonselection_line_color=None,
    nonselection_fill_color='blue',
    nonselection_fill_alpha=1.0,
)
c.selection_glyph = Circle(
    line_color=None,
    line_alpha=1.0,
    fill_color='blue',  # I plot the selected point with blue color here as well
)

c_sel = self.plot.scatter(
    x='x',
    y='x',
    size=4,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='red',
    source=source,
    view=view_selected,          # here the view should have the selected samples

    nonselection_line_color=None,
    nonselection_fill_color='red',
    nonselection_fill_alpha=1.0,
)
c_sel.selection_glyph = Circle(
    line_color=None,
    line_alpha=1.0,
    fill_color='red',  # I plot the selected point with blue color here as well
)
```

Each time you want to update the selections you will have to update the view indexes list:

```
view_non_selected.filters = [IndexFilter(non_selected_indices_list)]
view_selected.filters = [IndexFilter(custom_selection)]
```

Youcould create one single glyph with a color column as well and update the source. It may be more efficient.

Comment: Issue [is fixed](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7944) in bokeh 1.0. You can now simply update `source.selected.indices`

Comment: Yes, so I will remove the option 1 which is outdated. I will keep the second option as an idea in case someone wants to do something similar